# Evaluate $3^{{7}^{11}}\bmod {10}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How should I approach solving $3^{7^{11}} \bmod {10}$? I understand how to do $a^x \bmod{n}$ type of problems, but taking on the same approach does not work in this case.

Comment: $(3^7)^{11}=3^{7\cdot 11}$

Comment: What is $3^2\bmod 10$?

Comment: @kamil09875 sorry for the confusion its (3)^(7^11)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$3^1\equiv3 \mod10$

$3^2\equiv-1 \mod10$

$3^3\equiv-3 \mod10$

$3^4\equiv1 \mod10$

Therefore you only need to know the congruence modulo 4 of the exponent. For that, proceed similarly:

$7\equiv 3\mod 4$

$7^2\equiv 1 \mod 4$.

Therefore you only need to know the parity of the exponent. Then $7^{11}\equiv 3\mod 4$, and so $3^{7^{11}}\equiv -3\mod 10$.

Comment: $3^{7^{11}}\equiv -3\mod 10$ is true but I suspect $3^{7^{11}}\equiv 7\mod 10$ was wanted, to show the final decimal digit of $3^{7^{11}}$

Answer (score 3):

Note that $$7^{11} \equiv (-1)^{11} \equiv -1 \equiv 3 \pmod 4$$

However, $$3^{4k+3} \equiv 3^3 \times (81)^k \equiv  27 \equiv 7 \pmod {10}$$